# C, iNotify event->len is always equal to zero

Tags: c, inotify

I am monitoring file change in order to reconfigure my app, when the config changes. this is what I wrote (copied code from a "working solution").

```
    char *path_to_be_watched = "/home/user/ocsp_ca/crl/mycrl.crl";
    int fd,wd;
    //signal(SIGINT,sig_handler);
 
    /* Step 1. Initialize inotify */
    fd = inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK);
  
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)  // error checking for fcntl
       exit(2);
 
    /* Step 2. Add Watch */
    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd,path_to_be_watched,IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);
 
    if(wd==-1) {
        printf("Could not watch : %s\n",path_to_be_watched);
    } else {
        printf("Watching : %s\n",path_to_be_watched);
    }
 
    while(1) {

        int i=0,length;
        char buffer[BUF_LEN];

        /* Step 3. Read buffer*/
        length = read(fd,buffer,BUF_LEN);

        /* Step 4. Process the events which has occurred */
        while(i<length){
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];
            if(event->len) {
                if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE ) {
                    if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
                        printf( "The directory %s was created.\n", event->name );
                    } else {
                        printf( "The file %s was created.\n", event->name );
                    }
                } else if ( event->mask & IN_DELETE ) {
                    if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
                        printf( "The directory %s was deleted.\n", event->name );
                    } else {
                        printf( "The file %s was deleted.\n", event->name );
                    }
                } else if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY ) {
                    if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
                        printf( "The directory %s was modified.\n", event->name );
                    } else {
                        printf( "The file %s was modified.\n", event->name );
                    }
                }
            }
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
    }
```

But this does not work. So I tried debugging, and found out that `event->len` is always `0` even though the mask has a value.
So I changed the `if` condition to check the mask, but the line `the file... was modified` will appear twice.

So my questions:

1- Why is the `event->len` always 0?

2- How can I reset the event in such a way that it does not pick up the event twice?

Comment: You've set `fd` to non-blocking so when `read` returns there's no guarantee that anything has actually been read.  You need to check the returned value `length` and, if required, `errno`.

Comment: Thanks @G.M. for your comment. I was using`inotify_init()` before, still the lentgh was always zero... Moreover, it only detected the file modification for the first time; other modifications/deletion/ creation were not picked up

Comment: Is `mycrl.crl` a directory? From man inotify(7): *The name field is present only when an event is returned for a file inside a watched directory;* And *The len field counts all of the bytes in name*

Comment: @dimich, no this is a file

Comment: @PhoenixBlue So this is the reason why `len` is equal to zero. You don't need file name (and its length) when watching a single file.

Comment: `How can I reset the event in such a way that it does not pick up the event twice?` ? How do you know the file just wasn't modified twice?